# How to check internet connection one time i.e. not continuously?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building Xamarin.Forms app that pretty much works offline except a few calls to a web-service. Now I need to check internet connection just before I make a request, but I cannot find a solution or an answer that would allow checking internet connection only once not continuously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/) and specifically [Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?context=xamarin%2Fios&tabs=android) class as CrossConnectivity features have been consolidated into Xamarin.Essentials toolkit.

```
var connect = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;
if (connect != NetworkAccess.Internet) Message = "Device does not have internet access.";
else { // api call }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ConnectivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin) by James Montemagno

Nuget can be found [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Connectivity)

For check the internet you just have to do this:

```
if(CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
{
 //You are connected to the internet!!!
}
```

You might wanna check this: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/CheckingConnectivity.html

[Xamarin Essentials Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android) is also an option.

```
  if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
  {
      //You are connected to the internet!!!
  }
```